# Overlay plots in R

Tags: r

I want to plot 3 barplots together in one graph based on values from different columns of a data frame.

It should look [something like this](http://www.beckmancoulter.com/ucm/idc/groups/public/documents/webasset/glb_bci_003540.jpg).

The y-values of plot 1 are the sum of the y-values of plot 2 and 3. The color of plot 1 and 2 can be fully filled (e.g. blue & red), but the color of plot 3 has to be translucent.

I was able to make a plot for each column separately using the `barplot()` function, but I was not able to combine them in one graph.

```
barplot(covpatient[[1]]$cov, names.arg = covpatient[[1]]$exon, xlab = covpatient[[1]]$gene[1] , ylab = "read depth" , border = "blue", col = "blue")
barplot(covpatient[[1]]$plus, names.arg = covpatient[[1]]$exon, xlab = covpatient[[1]]$gene[1] , ylab = "read depth" , border = "red", col = "red")
barplot(covpatient[[1]]$min, names.arg = covpatient[[1]]$exon, xlab = covpatient[[1]]$gene[1] , ylab = "read depth" , border = "gray", col = "gray")
```

Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: the link redirects, if you can't upload save it to image hoster and post that link

Comment: And please provide a reproducible example of what you did already...

Comment: try `par(new=TRUE)` between plots ...

Comment: @BenBolker When using par(new=TRUE), the three plots are indeed in one graph, on top of each other. However, my y-axis values aren't correct anymore. A new y-axis is made for every plot, which I don't want.

Comment: use `ylim` to force common axis limits and `axes=FALSE` to turn off overplotting of the axes (and possibly `?axis` to add custom axes)

Comment: @ BenBolker: thanks! Your suggestions worked perfectly.

Comment: ggplot2 package allows to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you want... but based on the graphic that you sent I think this will help:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)

covpatient <-list()
covpatient$cov <-rnorm(100,2)
covpatient$plus <-rnorm(100,4)
covpatient$min <-rnorm(100,1)

plot_covpatient <- do.call(rbind,covpatient) 

melted_plot_covpatient<-melt(plot_covpatient,value.name = 'Value')

ggplot(melted_plot_covpatient,aes(group=Var1))+
  geom_density(aes(Value,colour=Var1,fill=Var1),alpha=.5)
```